# Relationship between δ(base) and δ(coefficient)

Tags: arithmetic

What is the relationship between a change in the base (in a power calculation) and a corresponding change in the coefficient?

I have an existing calculation:

```
fooCoeff * Math.pow(current, fooExpon)
```

My MathJax is not great, but I think this is equivalent to:

$$
fooCoeff · current^{fooExpon}
$$

One of the inputs to this expression will change, `current`. The factor of that change we can call `δcurrent`. How do I change `fooCoeff` (what is the value of a factor `δfooCoeff`) so that the expression will return the same results?

```
(fooCoeff * δfooCoeff) * Math.pow((current * δcurrent), fooExpon)
```

So, I want the new expression to equal the old one:

$$
y · fooCoeff · (x · current)^{fooExpon} = fooCoeff · current^{fooExpon}
$$

I know that when `δcurrent` is 10 – that is, when $x$ is 10 – to get the same result it will not work to divide `fooCoeff` by 10, so `δfooCoeff` ($y$) is not 0.1.

But what is the correct value of `δfooCoeff` (or $y$), given `δcurrent` (or $x$) is 10? And what is the relationship such that given `δcurrent` I can compute `δfooCoeff`?

### Example

An existing calculation is done with amounts in dollars:

$$
fooDollars = fooCoeffDollars + fooBase^{fooExpon}
$$

I want to change this, so that all money amounts are represented in cents:

$$
fooCents = fooCoeffCents + barBase^{barExpon}
$$

Obviously, both $fooCents$ and $fooCoeffCents$ must be 100× the original. What are the correct values of $barBase$ and $barExpon$ to achieve this?

Comment: I personally find this calculator-style notation incomprehensible. Have you considered using [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)?

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your code correctly this is the mathematical question you are asking.

Given $f$, $c$, $a$ and a change factor $b$ in $a$, find the change factor $g$ in $f$ so that
$$
f gc^{ab}  = fc^a.
$$
Cancel the $f$ and divide:
$$
g = \frac{c^{a }}{c^{ab}} = c^{a -ab}.
$$

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my first draft of the question. See whether the current edit helps.